# gcc cygwin compile error

Tags: gcc, cygwin

what are the minimum packages to work with gcc under cygwin?
I have installed gcc-core, gcc-g++, gdb, binutils, make. are these not sufficient? when I try to compile a basic c code I get following error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find
 -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find
 -lkernel32
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find
 -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find
 -lshell32
```

there are dll files named user32 advapi shell32 in system32. does the linker search for them but not find?
is it a path related issue?  when I go $PATH

```
$ $PATH
bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

and echo $PATH

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/PC Connectivity Solution/
:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.8/miktex/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c
ygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/AT
I Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2010a/runti
me/win32:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2010a/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/S
amsung/Samsung PC Studio 3/:/cygdrive/c/Cygwin/bin:/cygdrive/c/Cygwin/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, you are using MingW features (user32 is a Microsoft library, not a POSIX one). So you should install the MingW packages. [Here](https://devzone.cablelabs.com/widget/web/ocapri/1/-/wiki/OCAP%20RI%20Public/Build%20Environment%20-%20Cygwin%20MinGW) is a list; I doubt you need all of them, though (the exact set will depend on the application you are trying to build).

Comment: Unfortunately, your link is broken and site **cablelabs.com** does not have sub-domain **devzone** (at least, for public access). Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -L/lib/w32api (and maybe -I/usr/inclulde/w32api if your code includes "windows.h") to the gcc options.

You can also look for the LDFLAGS in your makefile and add it with "-L/lib/w32api" (without quotes). You can do the same with the CFLAGS variable if you need the include path mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the `w32api` in the folders.

Go to: `C:\cygwin\usr\lib\w32api` and copy all the files into `C:\cygwin\usr\lib` and `C:\cygwin\lib` That should fix the `-luser32` errors.

Comment: You shouldn't do that I think. They are put in separate directories for a reason. Use compile and link-time arguments and options to get it right. If you are building with mingw features you either should use -mno-cygwin (pre-gcc4) or a mingw cross compiler (which is available in the cygwin installer 'setup.exe').